# CameraX flashlight enabled

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-camera2, android-camerax

I can’t figure out how to turn on the flashlight? The trigger works, but the flashlight itself does not turn on (or does not turn off).

```kotlin
val cameraProviderFuture = remember {
    ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context)
}

var flashlightEnabled by remember {
    mutableStateOf(false)
}

IconButton(
    onClick = { flashlightEnabled = !flashlightEnabled }
) {
    Icon(
        painter = painterResource(
            if (flashlightEnabled)
                R.drawable.round_flash_on_24
            else
                R.drawable.round_flash_off_24
        ),
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
    
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        val previewView = PreviewView(context)
        
        val selector = CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
            .build()
        
        val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
        
        val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .build()
        
        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
            BarcodeAnalyzerMLKit { format, value ->
                onNavigateToDetail(format, value)
            }
        )

        try {
            cameraProviderFuture.get().bindToLifecycle(
                lifecycleOwner,
                selector,
                preview,
                imageAnalysis
            ).apply {
                if (cameraInfo.hasFlashUnit()) {
                    cameraControl.enableTorch(flashlightEnabled)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        
        previewView
    }
)
```

As I understand it, after the camera is initialized, it is not updated in any way. The only solution is to add a camera variable at a higher level and control this variable?

```kotlin
val camera = remember<Camera?> { null }

IconButton(
    onClick = { 
        flashlightEnabled = !flashlightEnabled
        
        if (camera?.cameraInfo!!.hasFlashUnit()) {
            camera?.cameraControl!!.enableTorch(flashlightEnabled)
        }
    }
) {
    Icon(
        painter = painterResource(
            if (flashlightEnabled)
                R.drawable.round_flash_on_24
            else
                R.drawable.round_flash_off_24
        ),
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```